# How to use Pandas with Python Networkx using read_csv?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, networkx

I have a CSV file which I must use to create a Network using **Networkx** and **Pandas** library, the data is (net.csv) -

```
,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
1,0,0.257905291,0.775104118,0.239086843,0.002313744,0.416936603,0.194817214,0.163350301,0.252043807,0.251272559
2,0.346100279,0,0.438892758,0.598885794,0.002263231,0.406685237,0.523850975,0.257660167,0.206302228,0.161385794
3,0.753358102,0.222349243,0,0.407830809,0.001714776,0.507573592,0.169905687,0.139611318,0.187910832,0.326950557
4,0.185342928,0.571302688,0.51784403,0,0.003231018,0.295197533,0.216184462,0.153032751,0.216331326,0.317961522
5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
6,0.478164621,0.418192795,0.646810223,0.410746629,0.002414973,0,0.609176897,0.203461461,0.157576977,0.636747837
7,0.24894327,0.522914349,0.33948832,0.316240267,0.002335929,0.639377086,0,0.410011123,0.540266963,0.587764182
8,0.234017887,0.320967208,0.285193773,0.258198079,0.003146737,0.224412057,0.411725737,0,0.487081815,0.469526333
9,0.302955306,0.080506624,0.261610132,0.22856311,0.001746979,0.014994905,0.63386228,0.486096957,0,0.664434415
10,0.232675407,0.121596312,0.457715027,0.310618067,0.001872929,0.57556548,0.473562887,0.32185564,0.482351246,0
```

Just for reference, it is represented in an orderly fashion like this -

```
    1           2           3           4           5           6           7           8           9           10
1   0           0.257905291 0.775104118 0.239086843 0.002313744 0.416936603 0.194817214 0.163350301 0.252043807 0.251272559
2   0.346100279 0           0.438892758 0.598885794 0.002263231 0.406685237 0.523850975 0.257660167 0.206302228 0.161385794
3   0.753358102 0.222349243 0           0.407830809 0.001714776 0.507573592 0.169905687 0.139611318 0.187910832 0.326950557
4   0.185342928 0.571302688 0.51784403  0           0.003231018 0.295197533 0.216184462 0.153032751 0.216331326 0.317961522
5   0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
6   0.478164621 0.418192795 0.646810223 0.410746629 0.002414973 0           0.609176897 0.203461461 0.157576977 0.636747837
7   0.24894327  0.522914349 0.33948832  0.316240267 0.002335929 0.639377086 0           0.410011123 0.540266963 0.587764182
8   0.234017887 0.320967208 0.285193773 0.258198079 0.003146737 0.224412057 0.411725737 0           0.487081815 0.469526333
9   0.302955306 0.080506624 0.261610132 0.22856311  0.001746979 0.014994905 0.63386228  0.486096957 0           0.664434415
10  0.232675407 0.121596312 0.457715027 0.310618067 0.001872929 0.57556548  0.473562887 0.32185564  0.482351246 0
```

I have a code which is supposed to create a network using these values but it doesn't work (networkx3.py) -

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx

g = nx.Graph()

connection_success_rates = pd.read_csv('net.csv', index_col=[0])
connection_success = connection_success_rates.values.tolist()

temp = 1
for row in connection_success:
    for i in row:
        if type(row[i]) is str:
            g.add_edge(temp, int(i), weight=(float(row[i])))
    temp = temp+1

pos = nx.spring_layout(g, scale=100.)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(g, pos)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(g, pos)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(g, pos)
plt.show()
```

I have no clue what is wrong, whenever I run it throws the following error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "networkx3.py", line 13, in <module>
    if type(row[i]) is str:
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not float
```

(I had help in writing the original code from @Adonis . This is a modified version, which of course doesn't work)
I also get different errors whenever I want to make small modifications.
Could anyone help me figure out what is wrong? (I do not want to modify the CSV file or its values). The first row/header and the first column/index are to be ignored as well.
Thanks in advance for your help :) (Using Ubuntu 14.04 32-bit VM)

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21207872/construct-networkx-graph-from-pandas-dataframe) answer, it should help you.

Answer (score 0):

The `for i in row` extracts the element, not its index. But since you need the element index as well, you should use `enumerate(row)`. So you can do this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx

g = nx.Graph()

connection_success_rates = pd.read_csv('net.csv', index_col=[0])
connection_success = connection_success_rates.values.tolist()

temp = 1
for row in connection_success:
    for idx, i in enumerate(row):
        if type(i) is str:
            g.add_edge(temp, idx, weight=(float(i)))
    temp = temp+1

pos = nx.spring_layout(g, scale=100.)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(g, pos)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(g, pos)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(g, pos)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did not get any errors, but unfortunately there is no network and I get a blank window. Any chance I might have to modify something in the loop?

Comment: Any suggestions on how to improve the code? I actually do not need `enumerate()` because it just adds an index. I only need the code to use data from the 2nd row 2nd column and ignore the indexes column (`1 2 3 ...`) and the header row (`1 2 3 ...`). Thank you in advance :)