# How to setup Pandas DataFrame and create networkx plot in python

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

I have the following dataframe:

```
data = [['tom', 'matt','alex',10,1,'a'], ['adam', 'matt','james',15,1,'a'],['tom', 'adam','alex',20,1,'a'],['alex', 'matt','james',12,1,'a']]
# Create the pandas DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Person1','Person2','Person3', 'Attempts','Score','Category']) 
print(df)

  Person1 Person2 Person3  Attempts  Score Category
0     tom    matt    alex        10      1        a
1    adam    matt   james        15      1        a
2     tom    adam    alex        20      1        a
3    alex    matt   james        12      1        a
```

I am hoping to create a network graph where:

a) there is a `node` for each unique person across `Person1, Person2, Person3`

b) 
the `nodesize` is the sum of `Attempts` for each person

c) there is a `edge` between each person where they share an `Attempts` and the thickness is the sum of `Attempts they share.

I have read through the documentation but still struggling to find out how to setup my dataframe and then to plot. Any ideas on how to do this? Thanks very much!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Construct NetworkX graph from Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21207872/construct-networkx-graph-from-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start by obtaining the length two [`combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations), and build a dictionary with the existing pairs of people (adding the attempts of edges with different order together):

```
from itertools import combinations, chain
from collections import defaultdict

seen = set()
d = defaultdict(list)
for *people, att in df.values[:,:4].tolist():
    for edge in combinations(people, r=2):
        edge_rev = tuple(reversed(edge))
        if edge in seen:
            d[edge] += att
        elif edge_rev in seen:
            d[edge_rev] += att
        else:
            seen.add(edge)
            d[edge] = att

w_edges = ((*edge, w) for edge, w in d.items())
#('tom', 'matt', 10) ('tom', 'alex', 30) ('matt', 'alex', 22) ('adam', 'matt', 15)...
```

And build a graph from the list of weighted edges with [`add_weighted_edges_from`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/reference/generated/networkx.DiGraph.add_weighted_edges_from.html):

```
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_weighted_edges_from(w_edges)
```

You can then obtain the `weights` of the graph and set them as edge width (downscaled by some factor) with:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
weights = nx.get_edge_attributes(G,'weight').values()

pos = nx.circular_layout(G)
nx.draw(G, pos, 
        edge_color='lightgreen', 
        node_color='lightblue',
        width=[i/3 for i in weights],
        with_labels=True,
        node_size=1000,
        alpha=0.7)
```

[image]

Comment: this is fantastic @yatu. Thanks so much I've got it working and if any quesitions ill let you know!

Comment: Do you know how I could ge the `node_size` to get the sum of each persons attemps? WOuld i need to create another list of the unique names and sum of their attempts? Thanks!