# Plot network from large pandas dataframe using networkx

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, networkx

I am writing on jupyter a program for the statistical validation of a network, the final product is a large pandas dataframe 5053x5053:

```
import pandas as pd
network = pd.DataFrame (data = app, index = products, columns = products)
```

app is a binary matrix where if app[i,j] = 1 the product i is linked to the product j. I would like to plot the network, and I just learned that it is possible using networkx (and sometimes other tools like cytoscape). Since the amount of data is large I have no clue on how to procede. Which kind of representation is the best and how can I obtain a readable plot? I have tried to write down some basic code, but results are quite disappointing:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.Graph()
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(network)
nx.draw_random(G)
```

Furthermore I have a vector of 212 green products serial numbers (indexes and columns of the dataframe) that if possible I would like to draw of a different color on the same plot.

Edit: I used the code and it works better than my try, but it is still not a readble graph.

```
G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(gg)
G = nx.relabel_nodes(graph, dict(enumerate(greenxgreen.columns)))
nx.draw(G)
```

[image: Subnetwork 255x255]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

I have used the dataframe (`df`) from the **Dummy Data** section below. This would give you a basic network-diagram. I would encourage you to dig in further in the documentation (see **References** section).

The `nx.draw_random()` creates a random arrangement. You have a lot of nodes. And so it will create a clutter. You might want to select a subset of the dataframe that has a certain number of connections at least and plot them instead to reduce the clutter.

```py
# G = graph
G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(df.values)
G = nx.relabel_nodes(G, dict(enumerate(df.columns)))
# nx.draw_spectral(G)
# nx.draw_random(G)
# nx.draw_circular(G)
nx.draw(G)
```

[image]

To draw the whole network, including the labels, edges, etc. use `nx.draw_networkx()`.

```py
nx.draw_networkx(G)
```

[image]

### Dummy Data

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import networkx as nx

%matplotlib inline

## To randomly generate array: a
#  Uncomment the following three lines
# seed = 0
# np.random.seed(seed=seed)
# a = (np.random.rand(25).reshape(5,5) >= 0.5).astype(int)

## To use a fixed representation of array: a
a = np.array([
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    [1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
    ])

nodes = list('ABCDE')
df = pd.DataFrame(data=a, index=nodes, columns=nodes)
print(df)
```

### References

1. [Construct NetworkX graph from Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21207872/construct-networkx-graph-from-pandas-dataframe)
2. [Documentation: `networkx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_dataframe`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_dataframe.html)
3. [Documentation: `networkx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_edgelist`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_edgelist.html)

Comment: @Rodolfo-Moreschi Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Thanks, yes pretty much it is, I'll try right away, the only problem is that having a lot of nodes I don't know how to make a readable graph. I'll try and post the code and image.

Comment: I've just added a sample of the graphs, is it a subnetwork smaller than the network itself (that is 5053x5053)

Comment: Working on the parameters of the plot (nodes size and color, and edge color and width), but it took me one day to learn how to do it